# Vue: Обратиться к методу компонента снаружи

Tags: vue.js

Имею компонент CmpTable из компонентов CmpModel. Каждый CmpModel имеет кнопку "редактировать", которая по задумке должна вызывать модалку с формой редактирования, которая лежит внутри компонента CmpEdit. При нажатии на кнопку "редактировать" вызывается метод CmpModal'а, который обращается к CmpEdit. По идее, он должен вызывать метод CmpEdit.show(), передавая в него данные CmpModel'а для обработки. Да что-то не получается вызвать этот метод. В инете пишут, что так делать можно. Но у меня не работает. Во Vue я новичок. Доки смотрю регулярно, но понимаю пока не всё. Опыта мало. Буду благодарен за помощь. Критика кода приветствуется.

.js:

```
/* Import Vue Components
========================================================================== */
import TableComponent from './component/TableComponent.vue';
import EditComponent from './component/EditComponent.vue';

/* Creating Vue Components
========================================================================== */

window.CmpTable = new Vue({
    el: '#table-component',
    components: { TableComponent }
});

window.CmpEdit = new Vue({
    el: '#edit-component',
    components: { EditComponent }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="table-component">
    <table-component></table-component>
</div>

<div id="edit-component">
    <edit-component></edit-component>
</div>
```

CmpEdit:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="modal-edit" uk-modal>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        show: function() {
            UIkit.modal(this.element).show(); // Пусть вас не пугает UIkit.modal(). Это стороння либа CSS-фраймворка. К вопросу отношения не имеет.
        },
    },
    computed: {
        element: function() {
            return document.getElementById('modal-edit');
        },
    }
}
```

CmpTable:

```
export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        showModalEdit: function() {
            CmpEdit.show(); // Пока без параметров
            // CmpEdit здесь присутствует. console.log() его печатает. При вызове метода выдает ошибку, что такого метода не существует.
        },
    },
```

}

Comment: У вас не два компонента, у вас два отдельных приложения на странице. Посмотрите https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html, прямо первый раздел "Базовый пример".

Comment: Вижу. Действительно...Это всё объясняет. Глупо, что я упустил эту деталь. 
Спасибо за ответ.